# How do I go about removing texture from a scanned photo?

Tags: noise-removal, texture

This photo is going to be used for a departed family members funeral service. What would be the best way to remove the texture?[image]

Comment: This looks like a picture of a photo rather than a scan, judging by the highlights. In addition to the answers given, you'll have much better (more uniform) results if you actually scan the photo on a flatbed scanner than if you take a photo of the photo. If you must take a photo, use no flash (or otherwise use wide, diffuse lighting from all sides and angles).

Comment: My suggestion is to use a scanner, not a camera, and set it to descreen.  You will need to do several scans at different descreening settings to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for your loss.

I used a Fourier transform method (in GIMP with the G'MIC plugin) for most of the texture, but it doesn't seem to work for some other parts and I have to wing it from there.  Here's a version put together somewhat quickly you may be able to take further :

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is s much better than the High Pass inversion technique I was using in photoshop. Also thanks for the plugin suggestion, it will be useful for the other photos.

Comment: @JosueIrizarry There are even better methods at the answers to existing questions here, particularly [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/33472/15871).