# Photography gets check pattern during saving/flattening in PS

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, troubleshooting, image-quality

I was working on scan of this "a little" overexposed analogue photo (cleaning from dust, some colour adjustments and curves). After saving a picture, this check pattern appear. I tried different formats - effect was the same. I only came to the conclusion that the appearance of this pattern is associated with flattening the photo.

Left picture is screenshot from open PS project just before flattening/saving as. Right is after. No actions between.
[image]

Here original unedited raw scan:
[image]

Scan, after some lightroom adjustments, before i move with it to edit in PS:
[image]

My layers in PS:
(working with colors and contrast, no sharpening, scaling etc)
[image]

And here are enhanced lines in: 1.before PS 2.after saving as/flattering in PS 3. screenshot from open PS just before saving as/flattering
[image]

How to get rid of it?
I work in tiff RGB 16B

Comment: The pattern is likely part of the original. Curves and other adjustments just make it more visible. Perhaps the following would help: [What is the best way to remove texture from a scanned textured photo paper?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/23445/75526)

Comment: @xiota Nope. Left picture is with all adjustments that i made and there aren't any strong visible lines. I can save this "original" version only via screenshot. Also in the picture there are indeed some vertical lines, but they are irregular, almost invisible and just few of them, but in original there are none horizontal lines that just appeared on the right.
This is film scan, not textured photo paper. But thanks i will look it up.

Comment: Provide the original without your edits.  Provide more details of your adjustment stack.

Comment: @xiota I edited main post and provided more pictures. Look it up.

Comment: @Mikołaj What you see on the screen is likely a downsized version of what Photoshop is using internally. So is the screenshot. Resizing can average differences and make patterns less noticeable. In other cases it can increase moire, depending on the exact ratios, the contents of the scene, and the sampling frequencies (scanning resolution) involved.

Comment: @Mikołaj Screenshots are insufficient.  Can you export the original and upload the file somewhere for examination?  Same for the edited version with problem... export and upload somewhere.

Comment: @xiota Here you have a link to exported photo from LR before PS (1*), photo after PS (2) and PS file (3)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Cs4hiCxOCEfPGXYHSMKtafEDoQN8IL3-

*versions at last photo on the main post.



I know now witch layer couse it. Its "krzywe 1 kopia". When this layer is switch off this pattern dont appear after flattering. But i have no idea why this happend...