# How to remove wave stripes on a scanned photograph?

Tags: photo-editing

I have scanned some old pictures. The uneven surface resulted in white wave-shaped stripes in the scan. Is there any way I can remove them in Gimp (pretty inexperienced user) or other free tool?
Any help would be much appreciated!
Petr

[image: Image With stripes]

Comment: Is this texture actually on the original scanned print?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove texture from a scanned textured photo paper?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-texture-from-a-scanned-textured-photo-paper)

Comment: Can you disclose the make/model of scanner, and the software/version, OS? Also, what medium are the old pictures? Gelatin silver? Newspaper? BW>lab color paper? Are the lines  embossed in the original photos or introduced by what you are doing? Have you considered a copy stand instead?

Comment: As per other comments, need more information.   With anything like this, the best fix is to not get the texture in the first place.  As a rule of thumb, anything you can do with the scanner to remove the texture will result in better quality and less hassle then digitally fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

With some scanners, you scan the image twice, and rotate the image by 180° for the second scan. Then in Gimp you load both images, rotate one of them, align them and set the top one to "darken only".

However this requires a very accurate scanner, and many scanners [have a lateral distortion that makes such images too different to overlap](https://discuss.pixls.us/t/flatbed-scanner-geometry-accuracy/29481).

Comment: Interesting solution! Unfortunately, I actually had the image scanned, so I don't have the option of trying this myself. If nothing else works, I may try taking a picture of these photos with my cellphone. It has its own problems but still might lead to better results than this.

Comment: If you take a picture with a camera (cell phone or else) make sure that you have two light sources.

Comment: This is good.  It may be possible to scan the photo 4x times by turning 90 degrees each time.  Photoshop could auto align layers and you can set up a quick action to change layer transparency and blend them all together.  Not sure about Gimp though.

Comment: Yes but hardly worth it, plus you have to align  pictures with two different kind of distortions...