# What is the best way to remove popcorn texture from photo of old painting?

Tags: noise-removal, texture

I need help removing popcorn texture from this old picture. I have tired some online apps and AI tools but they were not helpful. I know how to use adobe Photoshop a little.

Thanks

[image: Popcorn]

Comment: I'm not sure that this effect is going to be reversible. The source image data is just not there anymore (most probably).

Comment: How was this image acquired i.d. what is the source of the popcorn texture? Also, what is the minimum size (horizontal/vertical # of pixels) you would accept for the image?

Comment: It appears to me that the texture is not a feature of the image itself, but the wall on which the image was painted (which was then photographed), in which case it's a more-or-less faithful image of the original source. Or it was some sort of "artistic" effect applied to the image, which is almost certainly irreversible...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to remove texture from a scanned textured photo paper?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23445/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-texture-from-a-scanned-textured-photo-paper)

Comment: The suggested duplicate does not have the exact same source of texture in the image, but perhaps the same method using frequency separation might work here as well?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke no it does not because the texture in the question you linked is very repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet without recreating image by hand is using wavelet decomposition. Here is GIMP as an example - it creates several layers representing details from finest (1) to coarsest (7).

[image]

And then merging and using tonal curve to restore some contrast:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks amazing. Thanks.