# Does compressing with chroma-subsampling multiple times degrade image quality?

Tags: post-processing, image-quality, image-compression

Suppose I am creating a large image files out of smaller ones. The original images (jpeg) already have chroma-subsampling of 4:2:0. If one were to put them together and save again as a jpeg, would saving it with chroma-subsampling of 4:2:0 (as opposed to 4:4:4) have a "double" effect, similar to re-compressing an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *not* using chroma subsampling, JPEG generational losses are pretty much limited to rounding error *as long as the same compression settings* are used.  (Majority of compression losses occur during the first compression.)

Here is what happens when an image is recompressed until convergence at q=90 without chroma subsampling (original, 1, n, difference):

[image: attempt to replicate ths-montage]

However, when chroma subsampling is enabled, additional color information is thrown away, which probably also affects quantization, so that losses are much more visible when steady state is reached.  Here is what happens with chroma subsampling enabled.

[image: ths-color-shift]

If you're concerned about single-digit resaves, the effect isn't so pronounced.

See also

- [What factors cause or prevent "generational loss" when JPEGs are recompressed multiple times?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99604/75526)
- [What does "frequency" mean in an image?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/40401/75526)

Comment: Thanks for your question in the other thread. It's useful info I've always thought about coming from an audio background.So to summarize, quantization does not seem to take place using the same JPEG re-encoding settings (only convert colorspace/rounding error), but with chroma subsampling enabled, quantization does occur? Is there some science behind that or just known evidence?

Comment: Quantization is a major part of the compression algorithm, but recompression using the same quantization tables gives the same results (within rounding error) as previous compressions.  However, chroma subsampling throws away additional color information, and probably also affects quantization, so that losses are much more visible when steady state is reached.  In both cases, with images I've tried, a steady state is reached after enough iterations (output n+1 is identical to input n).

Comment: Thanks! I was more worried about what it converges to rather than *whether* it converges, but you answered both!